# Displaying more than one webpage on a webpage

Tags: html, razor, webmatrix-2

Can anyone guide me.
is it possible to use Iframe tag to display more than one webpage on a single webpage.
I want to split my home page into four different parts each containg a page.
can anyone guide how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 4 iFrames for 4 pages. Arrange them in a table or whatever design you want, and set the source for each.